# Java Linkage Error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, linkageerror

I have what I hope is a simple SPRING project. At start up I get the following error message.

```
[7/9/18 14:48:27:332 EDT] 0000009e SpringApplica E org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication reportFailure Application run failed
                                 java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory.getDocumentFilter(Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Profile;)Lorg/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilter;" during creation of class "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$867/0000000024217480": loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@eff7d9d3" of class "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$867/0000000024217480" and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@c9a3bf81" of class "org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener$DocumentFilterFactory" have different types for the method signature
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:335)
```

I'm deploying onto a local WebSphere 8.5.5 server.

Here's my pom.xml file contents:

```
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
```

`<groupId>com.yourcompanygoeshere</groupId>
<artifactId>eacmanager</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>EACManager</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>`